# C# ASP.NET Graph API Invalidate Refresh Tokens?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure out if this is possible in the C# Graph SDK.
MS documentation shows an option to run "invalidateAllRefreshTokens" to kill off a user's access pretty much.

Using the graph client for user's in C# I can enable/disable an account but I don't see a way to just kill the refresh tokens.

Some back story if it helps. We have a process we worked with Okta on. Okta suspends an account based on someone being in a certain AD group but it doesn't kill O365 because people may have devices attached. So someone could still get email even though they can't authenticate with Okta anymore.

So I either disable thier O365 account or if I can kill their tokens it would force the device to reauthenticate with Okta and it wouldn't be able to.

Is this a REST only thing? If so can someone point me in the right direction for a CLEAR and EASY example of using the Graph REST APIs in C# for both authentication (using ID/Secret)?

Comment: REST is just a way of structuring API endpoints and their responses.  This is not a "REST only thing".  This is an OAuth thing.

Comment: Normally one would kill a refresh token, if you're able to access it. Can you show some links to the docs? Because I am not familiar with the used framework. Keep in mind that if a `invalidateAllRefreshTokens` call is not user related; all your refresh tokens (all user sessions) become invalid

Comment: I think I see my error. It is part of the Azure Graph API. Very confusing when trying to find information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user

Comment: Looks like that command is back in the current BETA API
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_invalidateallrefreshtokens